# jQuery UI Slider Range: keep button in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, slider

Is there a way do redesign the jQuery UI slider range,
so that the button stays in the slider div and does not overlap over like in
the screenshots below ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your code here so we can check where exactly the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: There is no code.. This is based on the official jquery ui slider range.

Comment: It works perfect for me.. https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: I didnt said that it doesnt work. I want to redesign the slider button so that the edge of the button dont overlap the edge of the actual slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the left end, you can just modify the css for ".ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle", and remove "margin-left: -.6em;"

The right end will require modifications to the javasript, the ui/widgets/slider.js
 file. On the latest code on github (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/slider.js), this is on line 602

```
valPercent = ( that.values( i ) - that._valueMin() ) / ( that._valueMax() - that._valueMin() ) * 100;
```

The "valPercent" would be a variable from 0-100, this is used as the percentage from the left. You need to decrease this by the proportion of the handler to the entire slider. i.e.

```
valPercent *= (sliderWidth - handlerWidth)/sliderWidth
```

Replacing them with the actual values (we use that for the slider and this for the handle because we are in a loop going through the handles) you would get:

```
valPercent *= (that.elementSize.width- $(this).width())/that.elementSize.width
```

Putting this after line 603 would make this work for sliders with multiple handles. For single handles you would do the same for line 645, with the following code:

```
valPercent *= (this.elementSize.width- $(this.handle).width())/this.elementSize.width
```